# React integration of asynchronous back-end call

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, asynchronous, react-fullstack

I have this function in the back-end of my MERN (with M not for Mongo but MySQL) application. This function fetches all stocks in the database asynchronously and returns it as a callback.

```
getAllStocks: function(callback) {
    var context = dbContext.create();

    // First select the stock to get its price
    context.query(`SELECT  * from Stock`, function(err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;

        module.exports.stocks = callback(err, result);

    });

    return result;

}
```

I have tried to export the callback in a variable in this line:

```
module.exports.stocks = callback(err, result);
```

And to call it in my React App

```
import { stocks } from '../../Backend/StockFunctions';
import mysql from 'mysql';
import './App.css';

import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class App extends Component {

constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
    stocks: []
  }
}

async componentDidMount() {
  console.log(stocks);
}
```

I have tried it this way and it prints an empty array.

I have also tried changing the function to this:

```
getAllStocks: function(callback) {
    var context = dbContext.create();

    // First select the stock to get its price
    context.query(`SELECT  * from Stock`, function(err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;

        callback(result);

        // Make sure that the user has enough of the stock to sell it (amout <= total stock qty)

    });
}
```

and calling it like this:

```
async componentDidMount() {
  getAllStocks(function(result) {
    return result;
  }) 
}
```

And then this is the error it returns:

[image: error]

How should I be doing this?

Comment: Are you trying to import and call a function from the *server*, in the *client*?

Comment: What you're trying to do is **not possible**. If you need to retrieve data from a database you have to expose an API endpoint in your backend that you can call from your client/frontend through an AJAX call.

Comment: Great point Jon, that definitely isn't right. Thanks a lot

Comment: @goto1 You are absolutely right, I will make an API instead!